# Which is the most efficient way to run a particular select query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, subquery, query-performance

If I run the following code:

```
select PolicyNumber, MAX(decpageid) as decpageid, Risk  
from StatRiskDecpages 
where PolicyNumber = 'AR-0000301132-04'
group by PolicyNumber, Risk
```

I get the following results:

```
PolicyNumber    decpageid   Risk
AR-0000301132-04    41        1
AR-0000301132-04    41        2
AR-0000301132-04    37        3
```

All I really want to retrieve though is the policynumber and the maximum decpageid (which in this case would be 41) along with the Risk numbers (Which should be 1 and 2)

The query is also returning decpageid 37 even though it is not the maximum decpageid for the policynumber because it has a different risk.

The results I would like returned are:

```
PolicyNumber    DecpageID   Risk
AR-0000301132-04    41       1
AR-0000301132-04    41       2
```

I have figured out 2 different queries I can use to return my desired results but I don't think they are the most efficient. The queries I came up with are:

```
select PolicyNumber,  MAX(decpageid) as decpageid, Risk 
from StatRiskDecpages 
where 
       PolicyNumber = 'AR-0000301132-04' 
   and decpageid = (
      select MAX(decpageid) 
      from StatRiskDecpages 
      where PolicyNumber = 'AR-0000301132-04' 
   )
;
```

This returns the desired results but I don't want to have to specify the policy number more then once in the query. Is there a way to call the policynumber into the sub query from the outer query?

The other query I came up with was:

```
select  t1.PolicyNumber,t2.DecpageID, t2.Risk
from (
   select PolicyNumber, MAX(decpageid) as decpageid 
   from StatRiskDecpages 
   where PolicyNumber = 'AR-0000301132-04'
   group by PolicyNumber
) as t1 
   left join StatRiskDecpages as t2 
      on  t1.PolicyNumber = t2.PolicyNumber 
      and t1.decpageid = t2.DecpageID
;
```

I like this query because I only have to specify the policynumber 1 time and I can also expand the query so I can return the info for multiple policynumbers.

What I need to know is if this is the most efficient way of writing the query? It seems a little redundant. I might be wrong but I think there might be a better more efficient way of writing the query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd probably use

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES PolicyNumber, 
                         decpageid, 
                         Risk 
FROM   StatRiskDecpages 
WHERE  PolicyNumber = 'AR-0000301132-04' 
ORDER  BY decpageid DESC
```

Assuming the covering index on `(PolicyNumber, decpageid) INCLUDE(Risk)` this will give you a plan like

[image]

Comment: It's funny that we get so tied up in newer functionality that we forget about the old standbys like `TOP WITH TIES`. PS no pun intended. Ok maybe.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I refactored your query. *(first I'll post your query with your execution plan, and then follows is my new query and the corresponding query plan)*

**Your Query**

```
Select  
    t1.PolicyNumber,
    t2.DecpageID, 
    t2.Risk
from
(
    select 
        PolicyNumber, 
        MAX(decpageid) as decpageid 
    from StatRiskDecpages 
    where PolicyNumber = 'AR-0000301132-04'
    group by PolicyNumber
) as t1 
left join StatRiskDecpages as t2 
on t1.PolicyNumber = t2.PolicyNumber 
and t1.decpageid = t2.DecpageID
```

The execution plan for your query is as follows:

[image]

And then I wrote the query like this, giving the same desired results:

**My Query**

```
select
    p.PolicyNumber,
    p.decpageid,
    p.Risk
from StatRiskDecpages p
where decpageid in
(
    select max(decpageid)
    from StatRiskDecpages
    where PolicyNumber = p.PolicyNumber
)
```

This shows an execution plan of this:

[image]

Notice the single Table Scan (as opposed to your two Table Scans), as well as the lack of the Nested Loops for the JOIN.

As for what looks better and more maintainable, I think they are both relatively workable.  Just some ideas and graphical representation of an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

@ypercube makes a good point that an elegant *looking* query does not necessarily mean it will be more efficient. I have no idea about your indexes or data size but you may want to compare the following window function version against your existing queries (I would check both duration and the quality of the plans):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT PolicyNumber, decpageid, Risk,
    dr = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY decpageid DESC)
   FROM dbo.StatRiskDecpages
   WHERE PolicyNumber = 'AR-0000301132-04'
) 
SELECT PolicyNumber, decpageid, Risk
  FROM x
  WHERE dr = 1;
```

You may also consider leaving the PolicyNumber out of the result set. You already know what it is, since you passed it in, and it's the same redundant data on every row.